# Cross domain issue with jsonp and HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, cross-domain

I have a web page build through HTML, Javascript and ajax. I need to request resource from another domain. The request is through HTTPS. My website is on HTTP. To address cross domain issue I used Jsonp as the data type. Here is my request method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/service/sv1',
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: { 'parm': parmval },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {

        alert(json.info);
    },
    error: function(xhr, statusText, err) {
       alert("Error:" + xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Still I am not getting any response! Chrome says Failed type and status pending.

Is there anything wrong in the above code? Did i addressed cross domain issue?

Comment: Why are you setting a contentType for a GET request?

Comment: What URL does Chrome Developer Tools show it is requesting (in the Net) tab? Does visiting that URL manually give you a JSON-P response? What does that response look like?

Comment: if you try to access the url without https, does it return result then ?

Comment: Is the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header set on the HTTPS site?